# Vue3: change data() property in an interval

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to change the data property in an interval, but nothing happens. I made a simplest code example I could:

```
data() {
  return {
    someProperty: 1,
    changer: function() {
      setInterval(function(){ 
        console.log('I am working')
        this.someProperty = 3
      }, 3000);
    }
  }
},
beforeMount() {
  this.changer()
}
```

The log works fine, the property also changes if I make an explicite button to do it, so there's no typo or something. How can I achieve property change in interval in Vue3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`changer` should be declared inside the `methods` option and use arrow function to get access to `this` :

```
data() {
  return {
    someProperty: 1,
    
  }
},
methods:{
  changer: function() {
      setInterval(()=>{ 
        console.log('I am working')
        this.someProperty = 3
      }, 3000);
    }
},
beforeMount() {
  this.changer()
}
```